# Entitiy Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

Hey I have a problem with the Package Manager Console in C# with EF.

The error starts by adding the migration [add-migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7djHN.jpg)

And this is My DbContext
[DB Sets][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33kU9.jpg)
My Entity is called Message and I deleted the Connection String but i have no idea why i can not add a migration.

Can somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong here.